# tracing a netconnection error in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, netconnection

I am having a problem with correctly identifying when a connection was NOT made while trying to connect to an external file.  It works fine if I have the localhost on (which is config.gateway1) but if I turn the server off I only get an error:

"Error opening URL 'http://localhost/amfphp/gateway.php'"

I've tried setting up try catches on both the connection and the call.  I also set up an event listener which is supposed to call a function onFailure (which at this point just traces the fail).  The error seems to occur when I make the call, and it doesn't work...but I can't seem to direct what happens when the error occurs.

```
    var gateway1:String = config.gateway1
    var gateway2:String = config.gateway2
    var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection ;
    connection.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,onFailure);
    try{
        connection.connect(gateway1);
        trace("It went in to the try of the connection.connect")
        //trace(connection);
        }
    catch(error:IOError){

        trace("It didn't work",error);
    }

var responder:Responder = new Responder(onResult,onFault);//onResult and onFault can be any name
var array:Array = new Array(kioskNum,questionNum);
try 
    {connection.call("dataconnect.retrieveInfo",responder,array);
    trace("It went in to the try of the connection.call");}
catch(error:IOError){
    trace("It didn't work",error);}
//trace(gateway1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Error while loading WSDL can be captured by using FaultEvent.FAULT

```
...
webService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, onWsdlLoadError);
webService.loadWsdl(<wsdl>);
...
protected function onWsdlLoadError(event:FaultEvent):void {
    trace("wsdl load error: " + event.fault);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add event listener for [NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#NET_STATUS) and check the [info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info):

```
    connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);

    function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
        switch (event.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Failed":
                //Do something on Failed
                break;
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Closed":
                //Do something on Closed
                break;
            case "NetConnection.Call.Failed":
                //Do something on Call.Failed
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When debugging, I also use a default case to trace out all the other net status event codes, this can be very enlightening at times  `default: trace(event.info.code); break;`

Comment: Thanks both so much.  apparently the case I was looking for was "NetConnection.Call.Failed" for some reason.  The trace of the code helped me figure that out...Thanks a million!!!!

Comment: @umamiMike I have updated my answer , so you probably can accept it.